# Смена DNS-записей c доменом и поддоменами

Tags: dns, ns

У клиента есть основной домен на хостинге vscale.io
домен.ru
и есть несколько поддоменов, которые нельзя трогать.
Развернул новый сайт на хостинге sweb.ru

Какие настройки необходимо прописать для домен.ru, чтобы сайт корректно открывался, при этом поддомены остались на старом хостинге.

Не могу найти help по данному вопросу.
Ситуация осложняется тем, что для внесения изменений в DNS необходимо до 72 часов.

Comment: 1) Домен = ссылка, если на сайт будут вести 2 разные ссылки - это ведь не поломает первую?)
2) Чтоб не ждать 72ч - смените ttl.

Comment: Как поддомены заведены в DNS? Если алмазами к основному, то надо переделать на IP